# Why does GNU `sed` sometimes create a loop without any branch commands?

Tags: sed

Consider the following surprising experimental `sed` code:

```
seq 3 | timeout 5s sed 'H;${g;D}'
```

...without `timeout 5s` this hangs the computer, (instead of stopping after 5 seconds), but first it will output:

```
1
2
```

Or add `p` to print the hold buffer, endlessly:

```
seq 3 | timeout 5s sed 'H;${g;p;D}'
```

What's curious is that only the `D` command seems to cause an endless loop, (*i.e.* try replacing it with a `d`, or `p`, or `P`), and it's not well documented.  The *GNU* `sed` `info` docs say:

```
'D'
     If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as
     if the 'd' command was issued.  Otherwise, delete text in the
     pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the
     resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.
```

But that doesn't warn the user about the possibility of infinite loops.  Presumably the `g;D` resets an internal line counter, and `sed` jumps right back to `$`.

Is this kind of looping without branch statements documented anywhere?  If not, can somebody explain how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a weird problem, but clearly within what should be expected.

Let's walk to the core reason one step at the time.

Testing `seq 5 | sed 'H;${g;d}'` will print 1 to 4, one number on each line, but not the last number: `5`, why?

Steps:

- `seq 5` generates all numbers from 1 to 5 one on each line.
- When `sed` receives the first line `1`, it is stored in the hold space (after a newline added by default with `H`).
- as there is nothing else to execute (the next commands will execute only on the last line `$`), the line is also printed (beside being in the hold space).
- for each line, it gets appended to the hold space after an added newline and also gets printed.
- on the last line, the commands `g;d` get executed. The first recalls the whole hold space, which is `\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5` at that point, and immediately erases it with `d` and stops.

To actually see the state of the hold space, you can run this sed script:

```
$ seq 5 | sed 'H;x;l;x;${g;d}'
\n1$
1
\n1\n2$
2
\n1\n2\n3$
3
\n1\n2\n3\n4$
4
\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5$
```

It is supposed that `D` works similarly to `d` but with a **huge** difference: **only** when there are no new lines on the pattern space. From `info sed`

> 'D'
> If pattern space contains newlines, delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.
>
> If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the 'd' command was issued.

So, when the `d` is replaced with a `D` to run this script:

```
seq 5 | sed 'H;x;l;x;${g;D}'
```

You get an infinite output. The `D` removes the first line: A number and a newline, yes, but it returns to the start (without erasing) and `1\n2\n3\n4\n5` in the pattern space gets appended to the hold space. On the first loop a `1\n2\n3\n4\n5` gets appended to the `\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5` on the hold space, making it `\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5`, it doubles. The exact value on each cycle is non-important, only that it grows bigger on each cycle.

Now, if we clear the pattern space just before the `D`, it may work:

```
$ seq 5 | sed 'H;x;l;x;${g;z;D}'
\n1$
1
\n1\n2$
2
\n1\n2\n3$
3
\n1\n2\n3\n4$
4
\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5$
```

And indeed, it does.

Nothing out of the ordinary, everything working as it is supposed to work, just a surprising side effect.

Comment: Thanks!  Adding the `l` for diagnostics was particularly helpful.